# D3.js sort table by number, then alphabetically (as a tie-breaker)

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js

I have a table with two columns of data. When I sort with column [1] I need to further sort based on the alphabetical values of column [0].

This will sort the table by the float values in the second column, but I would like to further sort the tie's alphabetically by the string values in the first column .

```
return tbody.selectAll("tr").sort(function(a, b) 
{
    isSorted = true;
    d3.ascending(parseFloat(a[1]), parseFloat(b[1]));
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return tbody.selectAll("tr").sort(function(a, b) {
   d3.ascending(parseFloat(a[1]), parseFloat(b[1])) ||
     d3.ascending(a[0], b[0]);
})
```

If the values at `[1]` are equal, `d3.ascending` returns `0`, which will cause javascript to evaluate the 2nd expression after the `||` (aka `or`) and return its value.

Note that if the first function call returns `1` or `-1` then the function call in the 2nd expression wouldn't even execute.